# VirtualBox Guest Additions Debian 9

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I've been trying to get Guest Additions running on Debian 9 in VirtualBox.
I tried to install Guest Additions via VirtualBox, via Direct download from virtualbox.org and via apt.
Everytime fail with Kernel headers. But I installed them as shown in several tutorials. (first I tried `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` later `linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common`)
The last thing I tried was working on Debian 8 where I had the same problem

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11 linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

The additions seemed to be installed. I didn't get an error when I tried to add shared folders. Before I got a message everytime saying that the GuestAdditions are not installed.

But after reboot I still have no fullscreen 16:9 display and there are no shared folders mounted

What's the problem? What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: with sudo  or as root    dkms status    Also  uname -r         You can edit your question for that.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox do you use?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Stretch (Debian 9). If it doesn't work for you, you'll need to update your question with contrasting information:

1. First ensure that `contrib` repository has been added to your `sources.list`. If the following command returns nothing you need to add it.

   ```
   grep -rq 'stretch/.* contrib' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d} 2>/dev/null && echo ok
   ```

   Expected output

   ```
   ok
   ```
2. Update the repository and install the necessary set of packages.

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
   module-assistant prepare
   ```
3. Mount and run the VirtualBox Guest Additions image. Ensure the DVD image is available by going to the Guest window and then using the menu Devices > Insert Guest Additions Image... If you get an error here that you cannot understand, report it back *in your question*.

   ```
   mount /media/cdrom
   bash /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```

   Expected output

   ```
   mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

   Verifying archive integrity... All good.
   Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.2.8 Guest Additions for Linux........
   VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
   ...
   ```
4. Check that the modules have been loaded into the running kernel. You *may* need to reboot to see this take effect (but I didn't).

   ```
   lsmod | grep vb
   ```

   Expected output (ignore the column of high-valued numbers)

   ```
   vboxvideo              36864  1
   ttm                    98304  1 vboxvideo
   drm_kms_helper        155648  1 vboxvideo
   drm                   360448  4 vboxvideo,ttm,drm_kms_helper
   vboxsf                 45056  0
   vboxguest             286720  1 vboxsf
   ```